# Is it possible to allocate space from one disk to another? (Small C: drive issue)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a portable device that has two disks, Disk 0 which acts as the C: drive and contains the system files and Windows installation and a Disk 1 which is the D: drive. It is not a single partitioned drive but rather two separate disks (the allocated space does not appear next to each other, but one above the other).

The issue I am having is that, by default, the C: drive on Disk 0 came with only 29GB of space, which it rapidly became filled with Windows updates and other programs. The D: drive on Disk 1 has more than 460GB and it goes largely unused apart from personal files and some programs.

**Disk partitions**

[image: Disk partitions]

The question is: is there anyway for me to move some of the free space available in the D: drive to C:? According to the Windows docs, you can only extend drives from unallocated space available in the same drive, and not from others. Is it possible to circumvent this or is there truly no way of achieving it?

In case it is not possible, how could I solve this? Should I try to reformat the PC and reinstall Windows this time on the D: drive? Is it possible?

Comment: It is physically impossible to transfer space from one physical drive to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your proposed solution will work, but you do have some options.
One, you could move the swap file to the D: drive.  Depending on how much RAM is in your system, that should free up maybe 4 GB on your C: drive.  Note that this is mostly a temporary solution, because your C: drive will just fill up again.

For a permanent solution, I recommend getting some disk-cloning software, and clone your system onto a bigger disk.  That way you don't have to reinstall everything.  Your current D: drive is a good candidate **if** you can find temporary storage for whatever is there now.  The cloning operation will erase whatever you have currently on Disk 1, but you can recopy it later after you get your system running.

Comment: I think cloning the C: drive into D: is the best option. However I got into the device bios and in the boot order I am not allowed to select a particular drive ([Image](https://i.imgur.com/3stLS0R.jpg)), so if I clone the C: into D:, and then reformat C:, how would I make D: the default boot drive? I cannot physically uninstall the Disk 0 because the device cannot be easily opened (it's a tablet-like device).

Comment: I had missed the fact that it's a tablet-like device and you can't physically move the disks.  That does make things more complicated.  I think you'll probably need to leave the boot partition intact on Disk 0, and configure it that to continue booting on Disk 1.  I'm not very familiar with the steps involved, but basically it's a dual-boot setup.  Once you get dual-boot working, you should be able to make the OS on Disk 1 the default.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a windows command to create a link between two directories:

`mklink [[/d] | [/h] | [/j]] <Link> <Target>`

[documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753194(v=ws.11))

The basic process is: you make an empty directory, you run `mklink` with the empty folder as the link and the target being the place to actually store the data. Once done, you can copy/move delete using the "link" directory and they will actually get put in the "target" directory.

So you could have `c:\stuff` linked to `d:\actual_stuff`

For existing directories, you would need to mirror-copy the directory to the target location (using e.g. robocopy), confirm the copy and then empty the source folder.

Exactly which directories you choose is up to you: the obvious ones are "program files" or "users," but there may be unforseen problems. I have never personally done this on windows default special folders, but it is easy to find information (google: mklink program files)

It is a good idea to test and try out the process first before making big changes.